# allure-results path directory change from Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, allure

I tired different ways to configure the path where every Job result will be created but without success. I have different jobs for different applications in similar projects. All the results are generated in allure-results folder, and I cannot change it. Tried a lot of solutions. Worked for allure-report. but not for allure-results.

I'm expecting that every job result to be stored in different folder.

[image: 1]